# How can I delete a model in Tensorflow.js?

Tags: javascript, memory-management, tensorflow.js

When reading the official documentation, I am aware that when handling Tensors directly one must explicitly destroy them after use to avoid memory leaks:

```
let mytensor = tf.tensor([1, 2, 3, 4]);
tf.dispose(mytensor);
```

However, what can one do to dispose of a *model*? Is simply calling `mymodel.dispose()` enough, or is there something else I should do?

Answer (score 1):

A model contains layers. Each layer contains weights that can be disposed. To dispose these weights, [layer.dispose](https://js.tensorflow.org/api/latest/#tf.layers.Layer.dispose) can be used.

```
model.layers.forEach(l => l.dispose())
```